# jQuery plugin preventing .on(click) behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to trigger an action on clicking a [Selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/) dropdown.

**Current Behaviour**

The action is only occurring when clicking on the Selectric dropdown the second time.

**Steps To Reproduce**

01) In Firefox, with Firebug enabled, go to:

http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/demo.html.

*(It is running v1.8.5 of the script - the same version that I am using)*

02) Add this to the console in Firebug and run it:

```
$(document).on("click",".selectric:first", function () {
console.log("hello world!");
});
```

03) Click on the label of the first selectric dropdown (nothing will happen).

04) Whilst the dropdown is still open, click on it again and `hello world!" will be printed to the console.

So what seems to be happening is that the plugin is preventing the `on()` method from firing the first time.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle ?

Comment: I can't find the latest version of the plugin on any CDN, so therefore can't include script on JSFiddle.

Comment: Paste into the fiddle whatever plugin code you have, or put it on a server and link it in...

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the plugin needing to stop propagation in certain conditions. You should probably use the events selectric supplies wich are actually triggered on the select element itself http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place your code in _open function at line 347. i can't understand why e.stopPropagation() at line 352 stops your event handler